# Rancher on K8s (not helm) permission issues

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher-2

I'm trying to teach myself K8s and am running into some issues that I've been unsuccessfully googleing / stack searching. I'm trying to setup Rancher without using helm. Here's my deployment manifest:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rancher
  labels:
    app: rancher
  namespace: cattle-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rancher
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rancher
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rancher
          image: rancher/rancher
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

However, the pod goes into a crashloop. Logs show what look like permissions issues.

```
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [INFO] No access to list CRDs, assuming CRDs are pre-created.
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to retrieve feature unsupported-storage-drivers in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io "unsupported-storage-drivers" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot get resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to create feature unsupported-storage-drivers in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot create resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to retrieve feature istio-virtual-service-ui in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io "istio-virtual-service-ui" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot get resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to create feature istio-virtual-service-ui in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot create resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to retrieve feature proxy in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io "proxy" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot get resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to retrieve feature multi-cluster-management in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io "multi-cluster-management" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot get resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to retrieve feature fleet in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io "fleet" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot get resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [ERROR] unable to create feature fleet in initialize features: features.management.cattle.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot create resource "features" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope
2020/11/19 15:21:34 [FATAL] creating CRD store customresourcedefinitions.apiextensions.k8s.io is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:cattle-system:default" cannot list resource "customresourcedefinitions" in API group "apiextensions.k8s.io" at the cluster scope
```

Anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 2):

I was missing a Service Account and ClusterRole. Added the following:

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: rancher
  labels:
    app: rancher
  namespace: cattle-system
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: rancher
  labels:
    app: rancher
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: rancher
    namespace: cattle-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Now it runs without error.